# Values are not populating from form to html from @requestmapping in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to add/print two values coming from html and showing the addition into another html. So first request is coming to endpoint `@GetMapping("/addition")` and it is opening a `form`, In `form` action I have given another endpoint `@PostMapping("/submit")` and it should send values on another html but it is printing the only hardcode values not coming from form.

**So here the controller part:**

```
@GetMapping("/addition")
public String getInputForm(Model model) {
 model.addAttribute("addpojo", new AddPojo());
    return "addition"; 
}   

@PostMapping("/submit")
public String SubmitForm(@RequestParam("a") int a, @RequestParam("b") int b, AddPojo addpojo, Model model) {
addpojo.setA(a); addpojo.setB(b);

model.addAttribute("com", addpojo);
    return "added";

}
```

**AddPojo.java**

public class AddPojo {

```
private int a;    
private int b;
getter and setters....
```

**addition.html:**

`<form action="#" th:action="@{/submit}" th:object="${addpojo}" method="POST">
  First Value:<input type="text" name="a" th:field="*{a}"/>
  Second Value:<input type="text" name="b" th:field="*{b}"/>
        <p><input type="submit" value="add" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>`

**added.html**

`<body>
<!--  ${add.a + add.b}   -->
Addition of two values is: ${com.a+com.b}
</body>`

Comment: do you get values of `a` and `b` in SubmitForm(..){} method ?

Comment: no, I am not getting any values on html. only I get is ${com.a+com.b}

Comment: I was asking about controller, in controller submitForm method. if you..

Comment: @Deepak Can you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you write your controller like this you will get the expected result. Receive an object with @ModelAttribute. No need of RequestParam.

```
@PostMapping("/submit")
public String SubmitForm(@ModelAttribute("addpojo") AddPojo addpojo, Model model) {    
model.addAttribute("com", addpojo);
    return "added";

}
```

And in HTML to print your sum use this section of code

```
 Addition of two values is: <span th:text="${com.a + com.b}"></span>
```

Comment: still I m getting this "Addition of two values is: ${com.a+com.b}" value only not from form

Comment: For debugging purpose print value of object `addpojo` in controller whether proper value coming from the form or not! And can you post your `html` code?

Comment: I did debugging also values coming from form to controller but after that it is not going to next html.

Comment: I have already paste my html code above. when I am trying to print coming values in controller like Sysyem.out.print(addpojo.getA());  but his is also not printing at controller.

Comment: What you get when you print `Sysyem.out.print(addpojo.getA()); ` ? @Deepak

Comment: @Deepak Can you check by writing HTML code like mine?

Comment: its working now. problem was with form style as it is a spring form. so there is different way to fetch object to html. Thanks men for you help.

Comment: @Deepak  If this answer is helpful for you can you mark this answer as important one?

Answer (score 0):

Values that you take from your HTML from won't be taken as integers to your method. Therefor you should make your parameters string instead of integer.Below method was success in testing.

```
@PostMapping("/submit")
    public String SubmitForm(@RequestParam("a") String a, @RequestParam("b") String b, Model model,AddPojo addPojo) {

        addPojo.setA(Integer.parseInt(a));
        addPojo.setB(Integer.parseInt(b));

        model.addAttribute("com", addPojo);
        return "added";

    }
```

Comment: Can you please test above solution and provide a feedback. So that i can help you. @Deepak

Comment: It is still not working. while debugging values a & b is coming to controller but after that it is not going to added.html

Comment: I tried this also but this is also not working.

@PostMapping("/submit") public String SubmitForm(@ModelAttribute("addpojo") AddPojo addpojo, Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("com2", addpojo.getB()); 
   model.addAttribute("com1", addpojo.getA()); 
   return "added";
 }

And in added.html I am printing ${com1 +com2}  but it is printing  ${com1 +com2} only in added.html